# How to perform action when tab changes?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a problem whereby I need to remove data from a `DataGrid` whenever a `TabItem` header is clicked (i.e. a new tab has been selected). Problem is, that by using a `SelectionChanged` is that the event is fired when the DataGrid is clicked on as well.

I tried finding different solutions, like using a label inside the `TabItem.Header` (per another thread on SO), but that caused it to loose the style used by (Metro MaHapps). I tried `MouseLeftButtonDown`, but that doesn't trigger on TabItem.

So is there any other event I can use?

Sample code:

```
    <Controls:MetroAnimatedSingleRowTabControl Grid.Row="1">
        <TabItem Header="shifts">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="0.5*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <DataGrid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="5"  Name="ShiftGridView" />
                <Button Style="{DynamicResource SquareButtonStyle}" Width="100" Height="35" Content="Start shift" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" Click="StartButton_Click" />
                <Button Style="{DynamicResource AccentedSquareButtonStyle}" Width="100" Height="35" Content="Stop shift" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="2"  Click="StopButton_Click" />
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="stats">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="0.40*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="0.40*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="0.40*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="0.40*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="3*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Text="Dates"
                       FontSize="14"
                       VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                       Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
                <DatePicker Width="120" Height="30"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                        FontSize="14"
                        Controls:TextboxHelper.Watermark="Start date" 
                        Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Name="StartDatePicker" />
                <DatePicker Width="120" Height="30"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                        FontSize="14"
                        Controls:TextboxHelper.Watermark="Stop date" 
                        Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Name="StopDatePicker" />
                <TextBlock Text="Name"
                       FontSize="14"
                       VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                       Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"/>
                <ComboBox Width="200" Height="30"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                          SelectedIndex="0"
                          Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Name="NameComboBox"/>
                <DataGrid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" Name="StatsGridView" />
                <Button Style="{DynamicResource SquareButtonStyle}" Width="100" Height="35" Content="Show stats" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="5" Click="ShowStatsButton_Click" />
                <Button Style="{DynamicResource AccentedSquareButtonStyle}" Width="100" Height="35" Content="Print stats" Margin="10,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="5" Click="PrintButton_Click" />
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
</Controls:MetroAnimatedSingleRowTabControl>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SelectionChanged is **`Routed event`** that's why it *routes from DataGrid to parent TabControl*.

To distinguish between the events you can check **`e.OriginalSource`** which tells the *actual element which is responsible for raising event*.

```
private void TabControl_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // Sender will always be your TabControl.
    // So, just check if OriginalSource is same as sender (TabControl).
    if (e.OriginalSource == sender)
    {
        // Put your code here.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked beautifully. How can I learn more about this? Most of the information I find online (including MSDN) is so confusing on this topic.

Comment: MSDN have detailed article on this [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806(v=vs.110).aspx). Also you can refer to the site  - [WPF Tutorial](http://www.wpftutorial.net/). More or less you will get it with practical hands on.